# How to attach a metal rod to an air cylinder?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, wood, air

I have signed up for  an engineering class, and the first project is purely mechanical. I've never done mechanical work, so this is quite interesting to me. I have come up with the following project - create a snack box that can only be unlocked by someone standing far away from the box. Here is the image with the basic idea:

[image]

The problem I am having has to do with the rod attachment to the air cylinder. I can bend the metal rod to enter the hollowed out wooden piece attached to the lid, but how do I keep the rod firmly connected to the cylinder?

This is my purchase list - https://www.amazon.com/hz/wishlist/ls/ONWDBSI72VQ6?ref_=wl_share.

Since I am completely new to this - if you have improvements on the design, or better purchase suggestion please let me know.

Comment: use a pivot point ... examine a pair of scissors

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. how is it to lock? Perhaps retraction springs?
2. most cylinders have a piston with a thread or clamping section to fix to.
3. can two counter-acting cylinders be used which would mean swapping pipes on the pump or a changeover switch.
4. consider mounting the cylinder(s) next to the lock which gives more control of the rod and reduces any flexing.

These are points for you to consider and implement changes after you think about them - so I won’t be adding diagrams etc as this is your project.

Comment: 1. I expect it to lock because the cylinder has a built-in spring return.

2. I am not versed in terminology to search for the correct components to affix to the thread.

3. That seems to complicate the design significantly. I am trying to make this to be as simple as possible.

4. Now that is something I didn't think about, and is a very good point

Answer (score 0):

Barstock with a hole drilled in it can be attached to the threaded rod on the cylinder with nuts and washers.